# Sort array by current date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am looking to sort the values in an array based on the current date.

My values  :

```
[{
  date: "12-28",
  id: 1
}, {
  date: "11-30",
  id: 2
}, {
  date: "09-30",
  id: 3
}, {
  date: "05-30",
  id: 4
}]
```

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't really work :

```
var array = [{id: 1, date:'12-28'}, 
{id: 2, date:'11-30'}, 
{id: 3, date:'09-30'}, 
{id: 4, date:'05-30'}];

const now = Date.now();

array.sort(function(a, b) {     
    var c = new Date(a.date);
    var d = new Date(b.date);
    return (now-c)-(now-d);
});

console.log(array);
```

If it's November 29th :

```
[{
  date: "11-30",
  id: 2
}, {
  date: "12-28",
  id: 1
}, {
  date: "05-30",
  id: 4
}, {
  date: "09-30",
  id: 3
}]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you are wanting the data in?

Comment: You want to sort them by how close they are to the current date? If so then `2000-12-28` will be the closest to `2021-11-29`.

Comment: Hello, I mainly want to sort by month and day, the year doesn't really matter to me

Comment: I dont understand your ordering based on your output if sorting by Nov 29th.  Are you trying to put any dates after Nov 29th first and then any dates before last?

Comment: Let me try to put it another way.
Let's say that each date is a birthday.
I want to be able to display the next birthdays based on the current date. If it's November 29th, the next birthdays are :  `11-30` , `12-28`, `05-30`, `09-30`

Comment: I think the year is important then, if you have 11-30, 12-28, and then go to 05-30 the year is important, I assume that in this case 05-30 and 09-30 is in the next calendar year?

Comment: I don't know if the year is important. For me it doesn't matter. If I have `1988-12-28`, `1997-11-30`, `2020-09-30` and `1987-05-30`. I should be able to have an array in this order (if it is November 29): `1997-11-30`, `1988-12-28`, `1987-05-30`, `2020-09-30`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about turning `mm-dd` to `mmdd` and then converting to number and then using `Math.abs()` as follows?

```js
const arr = [
    {date: "12-28",id: 1}, 
    {date: "11-30",id: 2}, 
    {date: "09-30",id: 3}, 
    {date: "05-30",id: 4}
];

const dt = new Date();
const now = +[dt.getMonth()+1, dt.getDate()].map(v => `0${v}`.slice(-2)).join('');

const ordered = arr.sort((a,b) => Math.abs(+a.date.replace(/[^\d]+/,'') - now) - Math.abs(+b.date.replace(/[^\d]+/,'') - now));

console.log( ordered );
```

**All Dates Future**

If all dates are to be considered to be present or future, here is a concept we can employ:

```js
const arr = [
    {date: "12-28",id: 1}, 
    {date: "11-30",id: 2}, 
    {date: "09-30",id: 3}, 
    {date: "05-30",id: 4}
];

//converts m-d to mm-dd
const fmt = md => md.split('-').map(p => `0${p}`.slice(-2)).join('-');
const now = new Date();
const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const nww = fmt(`${now.getMonth()+1}-${now.getDate()}`);
const nw = new Date(`${year}-${nww}`).getTime();

const ordered = arr.map(({
    date: d,
    id
}) => ({
    date: d,
    id,
    d: `${d < nww ? (year + 1) : year}-${d}`
})).map(({
    d,
    ...rest
}) => ({
    ...rest,
    d,
    ...{
        t: new Date(d).getTime()
    }
})).sort((a, b) => (a.t - nw) - (b.t - nw)).map(({
    date,
    id
}) => ({
    date,
    id
}));

console.log( ordered );
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you very much for your help. However, this is not quite the result I want. The result should be in this order: 11-30 , 12-28, **05-30**, **09-30**

Comment: _...next birthdays based on the current date..._ So you want to take all the dates as being in the **future**? That changes everything; will take a look shortly.

Comment: That's exactly it, and I know it's not a simple thing to do ;)

Comment: Check out the second option that takes much of the processing away from the sort function.

Comment: That's exactly it! It's really perfect! A huge thank you!

Comment: Hello @PeterKA , I would like to re-launch the subject, because it seems that the change to December has broken the script. Indeed, the dates are no longer in the right order.

Comment: It broke because `"12-6"` is greater than `"12-28"` (string comparison); ensuring we always have the current date in the format `mm-dd` resolves the issue, hence the function `fmt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.sort()` to give you the desired result, I've moved the dates in the input array to this year:

```js
let input = [{ date: "2021-12-28", id: 1 }, { date: "2021-11-30", id: 2 }, { date: "2021-09-30", id: 3 }, { date: "2021-05-30", id: 4 }];

function sortByNearest({ date: a}, {date: b}) {
    const now = Date.now();
    return (Math.abs(Date.parse(a) - now)) - (Math.abs(Date.parse(b) - now));
}

console.log(input.sort(sortByNearest))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Nevertheless, the result is not exactly correct. Indeed, the ids should be in this order: 2, 1, 4, 3 (2021-11-30, 2021-12-28, 2021-05-30, 2021-09-30)

Comment: Oh cool,  I'm just not sure why 2021-05-30 has a higher sort order than 2021-09-30. Could you explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I understand that my request is not very logical.
In fact, the year is not really necessary, I mainly want to sort by months and days. I've modified my question, hoping that it will be a bit clearer.